# how do i get OLD photos out of my photo stream folders

Tags: photos, recovery, streaming

I have 700 photos on my photo stream (recovered after a lost phone! and older than 30 days) but I can't figure out how to download them. only the most recent (100-ish) photos upload to iCloud photos. How can I get all of my old photos off the stream?